# single sign on on ubuntu computer without using any server

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I want to try signle sign on on ubuntu
 computers without using any server.. how to implement this on local
 computer is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but i don't have the rep needed.

Single Sign On (SSO) is used for sharing credentials between software applications. Of course it is also used for login to OSs in different devices but it is only possible using a central access manager.

You can achieve that by installing [OpenLDAPServer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer) (just one of the ways) in one of your computers and configure others as clients to it. 
This way you won't need additional hardware (no hardware server) although you have configured one of your computers to act like a server to others.

As you understand this solution is only applicable for a small number of devices.

Comment: i have already configure ldap but other client computer not authenticated with ldap server ?

Comment: Check [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) is quite simple and detailed.